# How to make a UILabel act as a link to open a blank email with the address from the UILabel pre loaded?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have built a "teacher directory" of sorts, I have the data fill into 3 fields, name, position, and email.  All of the fields are `UILabels`.  How do I make it so that you can click on the email and it opens a blank email?

```
    @interface PersonDetailTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation PersonDetailTableViewController

@synthesize fnameLabel, snameLabel, emailLabel, person;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.fnameLabel.text = self.person.fname;
    self.snameLabel.text = self.person.sname;
    self.emailLabel.text = self.person.email;
}
```

(this is the table view controller where the data is being displayed)

Answer (score 0):

Use a button with a transparent background (UIButtonTypeCustom)

In your viewDidLoad use:

```
[self.btnLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(btnLabelTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.btnLabel.titleLabel.text = @"text";
```

Button action:

```
- (IBAction)btnLabelTouch:(id)sender
{
    //open email code here//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Add this to `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap)];
[self.fnameLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Next add a new method:

```
-(void)tap
{
     //Do whatever
}
```

Comment: where would i add this?  I'm sorry to be a pain, this is just really confusing me for some reason

Comment: @user2918086 `viewDidLoad`

Comment: it keeps telling me that i have an error, that i am using an undeclaired identifier 'gr'.  Where would i declare this?

Comment: ok thanks!  Now my last question is, how to i set it to open an email and take the email from the UILabel being clicked?

Comment: @user2918086 That should be asked in another question.

Comment: @user2918086 Do not forget the check and +1